# Why does `rd /S` say "directory not empty"?

Tags: command-line, powershell

I'm trying to execute `rd /S` on a non-empty directory and sometimes, it works fine, sometimes, it reports "The directory is not empty". Why am I getting this error? Is there a reliable way to remove a folder full of files and subdirectories under Windows? PowerShell's `Remove-Item` also suffers from this issue.

Comment: Have you checked file/directory NTFS permissions?

Comment: Yes. The script is running under admin privileges. If I run it multiple times, it will eventually work fine, like if every error deleted at least some sub-folders and eventually, the `rd` command would work fine.

Comment: Do the directories contain system or hidden files?  Try `attrib /s -s -h C:\directory` first.

Comment: Any running process somewhere around that dir?

Comment: The directory was created by `Copy-Item -Recursive` a few seconds before `rd /S` is called on it again. No programs have anything open inside that directory.

Comment: Do you have antoher (physical) disk to test your scenario there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be the local anti-virus or indexing service scanning and locking the newly copied files from being instantly deleted.

I would program a delay and retry on failure.

```
for (i = 1 to 10 etc...)
{
  try to remove directory
  if directory does not exist, break out of loop
  wait a second
}
if directory still exists, abort!
```

Comment: That was probably it although I can't confirm it. My solution was to use this PowerShell function: http://pauerschell.blogspot.cz/2010/05/problem-with-remove-item-folder-recurse.html enhanced with `Start-Sleep`. Nasty, nasty, nasty but the only solution that worked.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite likely that the undeleted empty folder contains some hidden files or that someone is still using the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
del c:\test\*.* /Q
rmdir c:\test /Q
```

Comment: [rd ... if exists ... rd ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22949687)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem exists in WinRE.  In an elevated cmd using attrib doesn't reveal anything, using del or rd both fail no matter if you wait or don't wait.

My guess is this is more trouble around the poorly thought out expanded attributes that never used to exist.  The same attributes that are causing problems writing large files to external USB drives.

You can spend 30 to 40 minutes or more creating a backup or copying a large file onto an external USB drive and suddenly you get a failure stating the device is read-only.  But look around because every directory now has a read-only attribute which is only supposedly applied to the files contained in the folder.  You cannot remove the read-only attribute from the folder and none of the files within the directory are listed as read-only.

Caveat emptor on the read-only attribute removal, sometimes it does appear like it's been removed and you might even believe it has but it will be back the next time you look.

Hard to believe another coding error in Windows that most likely will never be fixed.  There weren't this many problems with NT 3.1 and people think AI is going to fix everything. Lots of luck on that.  I remember when spell check was going to solve everything.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm trying to execute `rd /S` on a non-empty directory and sometimes, it works fine, sometimes, it reports *The directory is not empty*. Why am I getting this error?

Because it contains hidden files or files requiring different permissions.

> Is there a reliable way to remove a folder full of files and subdirectories under Windows?

Look inside the folder to see *what* files are left and check if you can manually delete them. If not, you may need different permissions. Try running it from an [elevated command-prompt](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/783-elevated-command-prompt.html).

> PowerShell's Remove-Item also suffers from this issue.

If it’s not a permission issue, you can force it: `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force …`

Comment: rd /s will remove hidden files as well, /q only enables quiet mode.

Comment: I did, *before* commenting! :) Just created a dir, added files to it, set some to +r, +rh, +h etc., then used rd /s to remove the dir completely after agreeing to the prompt. Worked fine for me on Win7 x64; no idea why it doesn't for you. Edit: @Synetech: Wait, did you remove your comment after confirming that rd /s does indeed remove hidden files?